# golang pars div value

Tags: golang

```
<body class="widget_frame_base tgme_widget body_widget_post emoji_image tme_mode nodark">
<div class="tgme_widget_message js-widget_message" data-post="hgfdhfghdfghf/2" data-view="eyJjIjotMTMzNjk4ODQ1MywicCI6MiwidCI6MTY0NzE4MzA3MCwiaCI6IjhiN2I4NDYxN2Y3YmU4ZTE3MCJ9" data-peer="c1336988453_-7513109051546167773" data-peer-hash="6af202fa41cc909675" data-post-id="2">
```

Как спарсить data-view?
Использую "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery" ничего не получается.

Comment: А чем [регулярные выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Zwek6z/1) не подходят?

Comment: Не подскажите как его использовать?

Answer (score 0):

на основе кода из readme библиотеки и godoc'а:

```go
// doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
var value string
query := doc.Find(".tgme_widget_message .js-widget_message").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    if value != "" { return } // мы будем находить только один value
    if s == nil {
        return
   }
   node := s.Get(0)
   if node == nil || node.Attr == nil || len(node.Attr) == 0 {
      return
   }
   for _, attr := range node.Attr {
      if attr.Key == "data-view" {
         value = attr.Val
         return
      }
   }
})
```